# Gulp dist build optimization

Tags: javascript, gulp

First and foremost, here is my complete setup, so that You may test it.
https://mega.nz/#!cZQUjZJR!eiDBDtDPKvn2LVsoQk_JfdU4alzrYx4ydSf_kuzkzvE

Everything is working fine, but I have two issues that I don't know how to fix.

1. When running a build using `gulp build`, everything works fine, except the fact that my custom JS inits are always excluded from the end result. Meaning, the `custom.js` file's content is not found in the `js/scripts.js` file. I have to add it manually every time, which is irritating.

   `<!-- build:js js/scripts.js -->
   script(src='js/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js')
   script(src='js/popper.min.js')
   script(src='js/bootstrap.min.js')
   script(src='js/highlight.js')
   script(src='js/clipboard.min.js')
   script(src='js/custom.js')
   <!-- endbuild -->`
2. How can I fix all relative paths in the document, because while developing, they are referring to the local server, e.g. everything in the result CSS file should have the following path `url("../` , while now everything is `url("/`.

And whatever you think that might be removed/optimized, please share some wisdom.

Thank You all in advance!

Comment: https://file.io/OtCo3J not found

Comment: @DharanBro , new link is up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, long story short, I had to use **[gulp-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace)** in order to sort out the relative and absolute path issue. So I added a small gulp task to handle this:

```
gulp.task('fixCssPath', function(){
  gulp.src(['./dist/css/styles.css'])
    .pipe(replace('/fonts/', '../fonts/'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css/'));
});
```

The other issue came from the fact that **[gulp-useref](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-useref)** does not understand **[PugJS](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html)** which I use for templating, so the basic html comments that I have used in my pug file, were not the adequate way of doing this:

```
<!-- build:js js/scripts.js -->
script(src='js/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js')
script(src='js/popper.min.js')
script(src='js/bootstrap.min.js')
script(src='js/highlight.js')
script(src='js/clipboard.min.js')
script(src='js/custom.js')
<!-- endbuild -->
```

So the right way to do this, is to use PugJS native comments, but without a dash (`//`), because using it with a dash, simply states, put a comment in my PugJS, and remove it from the end result, and therefore useref does not work. So this is the right way of doing this, if you are using PugJS:

```
// build:js js/scripts.js
script(src='js/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js')
script(src='js/popper.min.js')
script(src='js/bootstrap.min.js')
script(src='js/highlight.js')
script(src='js/clipboard.min.js')
script(src='js/custom.js')
// endbuild
```

Answer (score 1):

in index.html, I could see the  build:js wrapper

```
</div><!-- build:js js/scripts.js -->
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/highlight.js"></script>
    <script src="js/clipboard.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/custom.js"></script><!-- endbuild -->
```

It is not considering the line with `<!-- endbuild -->` and so it excludes `custom.js`

changing it to

```
</div>
    <!-- build:js js/scripts.js -->
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/highlight.js"></script>
    <script src="js/clipboard.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
```

brings custom.js to script.js

## update

use this `=` operator to write a line break

```
= '\n'
<!-- build:js js/scripts.js -->
script(src='js/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js')
script(src='js/popper.min.js')
script(src='js/bootstrap.min.js')
script(src='js/highlight.js')
script(src='js/clipboard.min.js')
script(src='js/custom.js') 
= '\n'
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Comment: This happens after the Jade(pug) is compiled down to pure html, how can I avoid the closing comment line being put on the last line?

Comment: @snkv use `=` operator in pug template

Comment: I've found a more intuitive approach, it was all about the PugJS comment syntax. I did not know the difference between `//-` and `//`. Thank you anyways!